# "Frames may be missing no binary loaded" for all my assemblies in the dump file, why?

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, crash-dumps, sos

I have a dump file which I'm trying to debug. But when I open it in the Visual Studio, I can't see any callstack for my code (only system `DLL`s), for my code it is only

> Frames may be missing no binary loaded for xxxx.dll

I do have right symbols.
Is there any way to fix it to see normal callstack?

If I debug in *WinDbg*, it can show only `EEClass` for the object and method address, but the name for class and for the method is shown as `<error>`.

The output of `.shell -ci ".dumpdebug" findstr "MiniDump"` is

> .shell -ci ".dumpdebug" findstr "MiniDump"
>   0001 MiniDumpWithDataSegs
>   0004 MiniDumpWithHandleData
>   0020 MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules
>   0100 MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData
>   0800 MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo
>   1000 MiniDumpWithThreadInfo
>   40000 MiniDumpWithTokenInformation
>   .shell: Process exited

Comment: Looks like the information shoud be there

Comment: I included the code/questions from your comments into the question.